# How to remove a special character "ï¿½" in plain text output in smooks/Freemarker

Tags: freemarker, smooks

I'm getting a special character "ï¿½" in xml file which has to be converted to plain text output in smooks/Freemarker, Please suggest which function can be used to eliminate this special character?

Comment: Why? Could it be that your editor uses one of the codepages (e.g. ISO-8859-x) instead of UTF-8, making you thing that output is somehow wrong?

Comment: Looks like a [BOM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark).